# Are two instances of pip & youtube-dl installed after using sudo to update?

Tags: upgrade, python, sudo, pip

I always used `pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl` to update pip and the relevant program youtube-dl. However, I started getting the warning:
`Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date:...`
First, I tried only typing `pip` instead of instances of `pip3` and subsequently only `pip`, but those attempts resulted in 'real' errors.
Then I went for `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip && sudo pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl`.
Both programmes were downloaded and installed, but the version of youtube-dl that was replaced was so old that I'm sure it's not the only which I regularly updated using the command mentioned in the first line.
Now, I suspect I have installed two instances of each of those programmes, one root and one not. Is that true? If so, how do I get rid of one - preferably the root one since sudo privileges are not necessary, I believe.
And off topic: What causes the original warning and how do I fix it instead?

Comment: You can update youtube-dl via the command "youtube-dl -U". There is no need to use pip.

Comment: if I remember correctly, that option was depreciated and disabled some time ago

Comment: No I use it regularly. And it works as expected.

Comment: And if you want to check whether you have multiple instances installed ( which I'm almost certain that is the case ) you can issue "cd /usr/lib/<<python version >>/ ; find . | grep youtube" command. or simpler one : just cd to /usr/lib

Comment: Just now I updated to the "(2020.05.08)" version via "-U" option.And it works

Comment: hmm, ok. Might they have re-enabled that option? I'm sure that's how I used to update the program

Comment: sudo frankly, the grep youtube command didn't work for me. However, by typing sudo ... and the normal command for uninstallation I saw that both pip and youtube-dl were installed twice and removed them accordingly. In fact both versions of youtube-dl because I wanted to use `youtube-dl -U` again, but:`youtube-dl: error: youtube-dl's self-update mechanism is disabled on Debian.`Are you not using Ubuntu?

Comment: I manually downloaded the [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) and added the directory to my PATH env variable. If you use the version which is installed from repo , the only way to update it is via " sudo apt install youtube-dl --only-upgrade". And yes self-update is disabled in youtube-dl which is in debian's repo.I thought you've installed it via pip.

Comment: Yes, I had first installed it via pip, but this gives the following message after `youtube-dl -U`: `It looks like you installed youtube-dl with a package manager, pip, setup.py or a tarball. Please use that to update.`
Uninstalling that I getting the repo one gave the error mentioned above. I'm just going to stick with the pip version. What causes the `Defaulting to user installation` error  is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997065/pip-python-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable

Comment: It should be a problem with the permissions of the `site-packages` directory. If you have similar problem consider using `chown username -R ~/.local/lib/python*` to make that directory yours.

Comment: I did what you said, but the warning remains the same. Anyway, this is a different issue. Thank you for helping me with the original one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you are concerned you might have several versions of the same software installed and that it differs between the user account and the root account.  Please correct me if I misunderstood you.

You can analyse this from the command line in the following way.

```
which youtube-dl pip pip3
sudo which youtube-dl pip pip3
youtube-dl --version
sudo youtube-dl --version
pip --version
sudo pip --version
pip3 --version
sudo pip3 --version
```

Post the result here if you need help in understanding the output.

Comment: hi, the problem has already been solved through Parsa's help. However, since that answer is in the comments, I don't know how I can reward it.